# How can I check if a parser is HTML5 compliant?

Tags: parsing, html-parsing

I am writing an HTML parser according to the official HTML5 syntax spec. How can I make sure that I have managed to precisely follow and accurately implemented the spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The de-facto standard HTML5 parsing tests are here:

https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/tree/master/html/syntax/parsing

So you can get them with:

```
git clone https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests.git \
    && cd web-platform-tests/html/syntax/parsing
```

Those tests are kept up to date with any changes to the HTML parsing algorithm in the HTML spec, so after cloning them you can run your implementation against those and examine any failures.

If you have questions about the tests and want to discuss them in real time, you can join the [`#whatwg` channel on `irc.freenode.net`](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=whatwg) and ask and somebody knowledgeable will help you.

---

#### Further details

The actual home for the *sources* those tests are generated from is here:

https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-tests

And if you want to (re)generate the tests from those sources on your own, there’s a script here:

https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/blob/master/html/tools/update_html5lib_tests.py